# What is the proper format to describe "X-ing" a number in dialogue?

Tags: phrases, terminology, grammatical-number

If I have a character saying, "He's thinking of 2xing our budget." What would be the proper format?

- "Two-xing"
- "Two exing"
- "2 exing"
- "2-xing"
- "2Xing"

Something else? I'm not sure.

Comment: It would help the reader if you first introduced that 2x means doubling, if that is what it represents.

Comment: I would say "2X-ing"

Comment: I'd use "doubling" particularly if discussing budgets (which suggests a business context). It's not a standard enough term to be in reference books, although if someone you know uses it, you can ask them/check what they use.

Comment: I doubt anyone would use 2x-ing to mean to double something.

Comment: So.  Spoken "doubling" might be written "2xing".  But if your character speaks it as "two ex ing" it will show how awkward that character is.

Answer (score 2):

the phrase '2xing' made no sense to me as a native speaker for over 60 years.
Doubling, trebling, or quadrupling, would always be used to indicate 2x, 3x or 4x.

Comment: Yeah, no kidding. Can you imagine someone saying they've been six-exing something and it coming off as them sick-sexting it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Using "X-ing" is a shorthand in writing out multiplied numbers. It's not a common speech pattern.

For 2X, we'd say "doubling." For 3X, a character would say "tripling."

For larger numbers, someone might say "He's thinking of giving us four times our current budget." (The word "quadrupling" exists, but starts to become less common than "doubling" or "tripling").